# How to download a file by web site URL and not file URL

Tags: android, asynchronous, download, task, progressdialog

I want to create an Android app that will download my own locations file from Google Location History and will display my locations at a certain date.

I know how to write an `AsyncTask` that downloads a file by the file url BUT
I don't know how to write an `AsyncTask` to download a file by a URL to a web site?

Whenever I navigate to the following url(to a site not to a specific file):
[https://www.google.com/maps/timeline/kml?authuser=0&pb=!1m8!1m3!1i2015!2i8!3i1!2m3!1i2015!2i8!3i1][1]
a kml file with my locations on 2015-09-01 is being downloaded automatically.
I would like to "catch" this download and display a `progressbar` starting when the download starts and ending when it ends and have the file content accessible for further processing.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2):

There's no difference. Just use that same URL as if it pointed to a file. Is all the same for HTTP.

Comment: I have tried it. I have written the code but get exception for the InputStream input line.: 
            [`code`](URL url = new URL(sUrl[0]);
            URLConnection conection = url.openConnection();
            conection.connect();
            // download the file
            InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream(), 8192);)
java.io.FileNotFoundException: https://www.google.com/maps/timeline/kml?authuser=0&pb=!1m8!1m3!1i2014!2i6!3i22!2m3!1i2014!2i7!3i6

Comment: Thats the same message I get if I open that with my browser. I guess the page requires authentication or some kind of previous setup. It can be done, but not easily.